# Update record from one table to another table with primary key without including set column

Tags: mysql

I want to update data from one table to another with different database without setting all column value in update query.
For ex.
UPDATE company.employee SELECT * FROM organisation.employee WHERE empid = 225

Comment: Hi Rupali, Please provide a sample data and query with your question so we can assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

**Method One:**

```
 UPDATE 
     company.employee,
     organisation.employee
 SET
     company.employee.firstname = organisation.employee.firstname
 WHERE
     organisation.employee.empid=225;
```

**Method Two:**

```
INSERT INTO organisation.employee
SELECT * FROM company.employee 
WHERE company.employee.empid=225;
```

You could try that, however, there is not enough information to establish what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to update the entire record.table contain more than 50 column.managing each and every column inside "SET" operator looks lengthy.Can you provide other solution on it.

Comment: I don't think you can use the 'update' statement without the 'set' operator.

Comment: Can you suggest the another option on it for my help

Comment: Method two is applicable when organisation.employee does  not contain empid=225. I want to be migrate only updated  record from database table to another database table with including same primary key

Comment: Thank you for Help                                                                              *Method Three :*    Using the below one with "SET"operator                                                                                                        UPDATE company.employee INNER JOIN organisation.employee
    ON company.employee.empid = organisation.employee.empid
 SET company.employee.firstname = organisation.employee.firstname
    AND company.employee.lastname = organisation.employee.lastname ...